# Adsense combination for reporting api not working

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying out the reporting api to create a report by using this url:
**https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet**

My http request body looks like:

```
{
  "reportRequests":
  [
    {
      "includeEmptyRows":true,
      "viewId": "XXXXXXX",
      "dateRanges": [{"startDate": "2016-10-01", "endDate": "2016-10-31"}],
      "dimensions":[
        {"name":"ga:date"},
        {"name":"ga:year"},
        {"name":"ga:month"},
        {"name":"ga:week"},
        {"name":"ga:day"},
        {"name":"ga:hour"},
        {"name":"ga:campaign"}
        ],
      "pageSize":"10000",
      "metrics": [
         {"expression": "ga:adsenseRevenue"},
       {"expression": "ga:adsenseAdUnitsViewed"},
       {"expression": "ga:adsenseAdsViewed"},
       {"expression": "ga:adsenseAdsClicks"},
       {"expression": "ga:adsensePageImpressions"},
         {"expression": "ga:adsenseCTR"},
       {"expression": "ga:adsenseECPM"},
         {"expression": "ga:adsenseExits"},
         {"expression": "ga:adsenseViewableImpressionPercent"},
         {"expression": "ga:adsenseCoverage"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The Metrics columns are exactly the same from the example on the official documentation here :
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=adsense

And I actually tried different possible combination of dimensions too(including empty dimensions), and I always get a 400 bad request response, the response is like this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Restricted metric(s): ga:adsenseECPM, ga:adsenseAdsClicks, ga:adsenseExits, ga:adsensePageImpressions, ga:adsenseAdsViewed, ga:adsenseCTR, ga:adsenseCoverage, ga:adsenseRevenue, ga:adsenseAdUnitsViewed, ga:adsenseViewableImpressionPercent can only be queried under certain conditions.\nFor details see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? Or is the Adsense combination usable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This combination should work. Is AdSense linked to the property associated with this view?

Comment: @vinoaj I dont think so. So is this the reason that I am getting this error?

Comment: Exactly. The data must be in the view for the API to be able to return the metrics. This seems to imply AdSense data is not available in the view for those dates.